# How can I document a subclass method with YARD?

Tags: ruby, yard

How can I document a method that a subclass overrides without being redundant? For example...

```
class Parent
  # Is this the parent?
  # @return [Boolean]
  def parent?
    true
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def parent?
    false
  end
end
```

YARD generates something like this.

> ### Class: Parent
>
> #### Instance Method Summary
>
> ```
> #parent? ⇒ Boolean
> ```
>
> Is this the parent?.

> ### Class: Child
>
> #### Instance Method Summary
>
> ```
> #parent? ⇒ Boolean
> ```

The generated YARD documentation will not include "Is this the parent?" in the docs for Child#parent?, nor will it indicate that it is an override.

I would like to see something like this:

> ### Class: Parent
>
> #### Instance Method Summary
>
> ```
> #parent? ⇒ Boolean
> ```
>
> Is this the parent?.

> ### Class: Child
>
> #### Instance Method Summary
>
> ```
> #parent? ⇒ Boolean
> ```
>
> Is this the parent?.
>
> #### Methods inherited from Parent
>
> ```
> #parent?
> ```

I would prefer not to have to copy the documentation into every subclass.

Comment: After rereading this, maybe all you need is the @see tag in subclasses.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs `@see Parent#parent?`?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Thanks, your suggestion helped me [find an acceptable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74648355/14660)

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Answer

The correct way to document this is to place a free-form description after the return type, and maybe document the method itself. For example:

```rb
class Parent
  # True when a passed argument has Parent
  # as an ancestor.
  #
  # @return [Boolean] ancestor of subclass
  def parent?
    true
  end
end
```

### A More Comprehensive Example

You can also provide examples of usage and more detailed documentation by leveraging the free-form parts of the tag syntax and your markup language (RDoc by default).

```rb
class Parent
  # True when passed argument includes
  # +Parent+ as an ancestor.
  #
  # @example Cousin isn't subclass of Parent
  #   parent? Cousin.new #=> false
  # @example Child is a subclass of Parent
  #   parent? Child.new #=> true
  # @param obj [Class, #ancestors] Class,
  #   instance, or other object that can
  #   #respond_to?(:ancestors)
  # @return [Boolean] ancestors of _obj_
  #   includes +Parent+ class
  def parent? obj
    obj.class.ancestors.include? self.class
  end
end
```

There may be more elegant ways to do this, and I'm typing on a phone so *caveat emptor* with the code as I haven't actually tested the code or validated the formatting of the YARD output. Still, the general approach is sound and I use this type of formatting routinely.

#### Core Ideas

Basically, the core ideas are that one should:

1. Place your description of each tagged item in-line if you want it associated with that item. Most tags support free-form descriptions or titles which will be formatted in a way that visually associates them with the tagged element.
2. Use tags and formatting for classes, methods, arguments, examples, and so on. You don't have to cram it all into a single tag, although in your *specific* example you probably want to do so to keep things visually associated.
3. You can [wrap long free-form text with indentation](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#multi-line-tags) in *most* cases.
4. There are a few exceptions to wrapping (e.g. [example titles](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#example) vs. indented code blocks is illustrative) but you can often work around that with RDoc or Markdown syntax.
5. If you can't get what you want, refer to [item four](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#common-tag-syntaxes) for some alternative approaches or find a different tag or markup to represent your intent.
6. [Macros](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#macro), [custom tags](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#adding-custom-tags), and [directives](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Directive_List) will let you do weird and wonderful things if you can't get what you want out of the box. *NB: I've almost never needed to resort to this, but the features are there if you need them.*

In most cases, simpler is better. Understanding how and when YARD can't succinctly represent your authorial intent is admittedly a bit of an art form, but code that's hard to tag or render as expected may indicate a need to *refactor the code* rather than just modifying the YARD tags.

### Keep YARD's Main Purpose in Mind

Just remember that YARD is primarily for ** elements of your documentation, and providing hints to a rendering engine or document reader, It's not a full-fledged markup language by itself, can't validate signatures like RBS with Steep, and doesn't enforce any sort of caller/callee contract.

It's all just comments. Make your code as self-explanatory as possible, then treat YARD as just one way to improve necessary comments by tagging documentation elements so the markup language generates better output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [reference tag](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#reference-tags) on each individual method to refer to the Parent methods.

```
class Child < Parent
  # (see Parent#parent?)
  def parent?
    false
  end
end
```

`Child#parent?` will have the same documentation as `Parent::parent?`